# Cordova Geofencing plugin not working

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, geofencing

I need to make an application which alert on the user when the user enters a particular geofenced area. I tried cordova geofencing plugin. But it doesn't work when I enter the area. I don't know what is the problem. Here are my codes.

app.js

```js
// Ionic Starter App

// angular.module is a global place for creating, registering and retrieving Angular modules
// 'starter' is the name of this angular module example (also set in a <body> attribute in index.html)
// the 2nd parameter is an array of 'requires'
angular.module('starter', ['ionic','ngCordova'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
           // $log.log('Ionic ready');
            // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
            // for form inputs)
            if ($window.cordova && $window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
                cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
            }
            if ($window.StatusBar) {
                StatusBar.styleDefault();
            }
            if ($window.geofence) {
                $window.geofence.initialize();

                $window.geofence.onTransitionReceived = function (geofences) {
                  //  $log.log(geofences);
                    if (geofences) {
                        $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                            geofences.forEach(function (geo) {
                                geo.notification = geo.notification || {
                                    title: 'Geofence transition',
                                    text: 'Without notification'
                                };
                               // toaster.pop('info', geo.notification.title, geo.notification.text);
                            });
                        });
                    }
                };

                $window.geofence.onNotificationClicked = function (notificationData) {
                    $log.log(notificationData);
                    if (notificationData) {
                        $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                          //  toaster.pop('warning', 'Notification clicked', notificationData.notification.text);
                        });
                    }
                };
            }
           
        });

})


//Entering Zandig

window.geofence.addOrUpdate({
    id:             "e941166e-2409-4c97-8c80-14ba9e9d71c9",
    latitude:       12.958535143383823,
    longitude:      77.6381016522646,
    radius:         5,
    transitionType: 1
}).then(function () {
 document.getElementById("notification").innerHTML= "Reached Zandig";
    console.log('Geofence successfully added');
}, function (reason) {
    console.log('Adding geofence failed', reason);
});

//Leaving Trivandrum

window.geofence.addOrUpdate({
    id:             "1e473337-4747-4ac3-b921-ccaf572f38ce",
    latitude:       8.487695348115592,
    longitude:      76.95057034492493,
    radius:         3,
    transitionType: 2
   
}).then(function () {
 document.getElementById("notification").innerHTML= "Left Trivandrum";
    console.log('Geofence successfully added');
}, function (reason) {
    console.log('Adding geofence failed', reason);
});

//Entering 61

window.geofence.addOrUpdate({
    id:             "8f8119ce-b577-4f22-9880-57333fcff5de",
    latitude:       12.9593547,
    longitude:      77.63604520000001,
    radius:         5,
    transitionType: 1
    
}).then(function () {
 document.getElementById("notification").innerHTML= "Entered 61";
    console.log('Geofence successfully added');
}, function (reason) {
    console.log('Adding geofence failed', reason);
});

//Entering Santhi Sagar

window.geofence.addOrUpdate({
    id:             "d2c08c58-4f31-44e9-8a5c-8baaae3ebee3",
    latitude:       12.960690294723518,
    longitude:      77.63856634497643,
    radius:         15,
    transitionType: 1
}).then(function () {
 document.getElementById("notification").innerHTML= "Entered Santhi Sagar";
    console.log('Geofence successfully added');
}, function (reason) {
    console.log('Adding geofence failed', reason);
});

//Leaving Santhi Sagar

window.geofence.addOrUpdate({
    id:             "6923cf7d-470e-4921-9b54-4516c504cba5",
    latitude:       12.960690294723518,
    longitude:      77.63856634497643,
    radius:         15,
    transitionType: 2
}).then(function () {
 document.getElementById("notification").innerHTML= "Left Santhi Sagar";
    console.log('Geofence successfully added');
}, function (reason) {
    console.log('Adding geofence failed', reason);
});

//Getting watched from device

window.geofence.getWatched().then(function (geofencesJson) {
    var geofences = JSON.parse(geofencesJson);
});

//Listening for Geofencing transitions

window.geofence.onTransitionReceived = function (geofences) {
    geofences.forEach(function (geo) {
  alert('Geofence transition detected');
        console.log('Geofence transition detected', geo);
    });
};

//When click on notification

window.geofence.onNotificationClicked = function (notificationData) {
 Alert('Geofencing is Working');
    console.log('App opened from Geo Notification!', notificationData);
};
```

Index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
 <script src="js/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="starter">

    <ion-pane>
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
        <h1 class="title">Geofencing</h1>
      </ion-header-bar>
      <ion-content>
   <p id="notification"></p>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-pane>
  </body>
</html>
```

(In the Github page of the plugin, there was an option that 'unique id for geofence'. I added the unique id from UUID generator online page.)

But no alert is displaying. Can anyone help?

When I run using ionic serve, in the console, the following error found. 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addOrUpdate' of undefined'.

Here is my console errors with device.

0 466310 error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property'addOrUpdate' of undefined, htttp://192.168.43.148.8100/js/app.js, Line 28

1 466870 error No Content-Security-Policy meta tag found. Please add one when using the cordova-plugin-whitelist plugin.

2 466930 error Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function, http://192.168.43.148:8100/plugins/cordova/plugin-geofence/www.geofence.js, Line 119

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you tell me..how to get this " id:  e941166e-2409-4c97-8c80-14ba9e9d71c9" attribute value

Comment: https://www.uuidgenerator.net/

Answer (score 2):

Here is a ionic sample project from authors of same plugin : https://github.com/cowbell/ionic-geofence , in it you can see total guide of how to use it in ionic. Your code should also work but you are doing few mistakes.If you want to run some plugin related code at initialization of application, put them into `.run()` part, you are using plugin calls out of that. Plus no need to use `document.addEventListener('deviceready')` as you have `$ionicPlatform.ready`, initialize plugin in that. Your code will be like this

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic','ngCordova'])
  .run(function($ionicPlatform) {
      $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    //Use your plugin related calls in this area
   }) 
});
```

You were getting error of `undefined` because you were making plugin calls before even their object was available to application.Again, any plugin related calls which you want to run at time of initialization, use them in `$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {})` .

Comment: I edited the code according to your reply. But still the problem is there. I updated my question with the edited app.js . There is nothing displaying in my app and also no notification is there. I build the android app and put it in my phone. Nothing happening. I tried even after restarting my app. No response. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

so I see you said you tested it using ionic server. you cant test plugins via the browser, you have to actually install it on the device in order to test cordova plugins. You can also test most plugins via emulation using the intel xdk. https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-xdk just import your project and emulate it then move to your geofenced location via the map on the right. Or you can hit the test tab and push it to a phone and test it using the intel app preview app on your iphone or android device. Last but not least you can use the debug tab to push it straight to a device using a usb cable and this will allow you to have a debugging console while you test the plugin on your device.

Comment: @jess_patton : I tried installing the app in an android phone. But no notification and nothing arrived even I went very close to the geofenced area. I tried on the browser only for checking the console errors. I don't know what the problem is?

Comment: if you want to check console from device, run this command : `ionic run android -l -c` this will show all device logs in your command line window. And make sure device and computer are connected to same network.

Comment: Yeah I agree with mudasser.  You need to debug it on the device in order to see the correct debugging output.  Once you do that post the errors and I will try to find a fix.

Comment: @JessPatton,@mudasser: Can you help me guys..?

Comment: Can anyone tell me..how to get this " id:  e941166e-2409-4c97-8c80-14ba9e9d71c9" attribute value

Comment: https://www.uuidgenerator.net/